# "No module named 'http_server'" when trying to import http_server in networkx

Tags: python, http, graph, server, networkx

I'm trying to work through the following tutorial (see here: https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/11/01/interactive-graphs-in-the-browser/). However, when I try to import http_server I get the following error:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http_server'". All other modules import just fine. My Networkx version is 1.11 (installed by Anaconda).

I'm trying to convert a given graph from a matplotlib graph into a JSON graph. Here are my import codes:

```
import networkx as nx
import json
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
import http_server
```

And here's the error message:

> "PS C:\Users\ ...\csv> python server.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "server.py", line 4, in 
>       import http_server
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http_server'"

Comment: may you write your import codes?

Comment: Seems like the author of that blog post forgot to mention where ``http_server`` should be imported from. Probably best to contact the author about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `http_server` is just a short piece of code that used to be in the examples directory, but was removed in release 2.0 (see [release notes](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/doc/release/release_2.0.rst), and also [pull request discussion](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/2001) for reasoning).

You can still access it, from the [commit where it was added](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/4e842c502fe6a9ade20ff4f6b3b95ebdd13ef9e2/examples/javascript/http_server.py) or also in [old documentation versions](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.11/examples/javascript/http_server.html).